# Trim a text file to desired length

Tags: c#, file-io

How would I write a function that trims a text file approximately to desired size in bytes? The file is a newline-separated list and I would like to trim it between the elements, not inside them.

EDIT: Example file

```
element one
element two
third element
hello
final element
```

I'd like to to cut off the file in a way that elements are kept intact, e.g. not like this:

```
element one
element two
third element
he
```

But like this (even if it means that the size won't be exactly equal to the parameter):

```
element one
element two
third element
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by trim? Do you want to keep the first x bytes and chop the rest of the file off? What do you mean by trim between elements, can you give an example?

Comment: please provide an example of the file you'd like to parse, and your expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read the desired length and then trim it to the last newline:

```
 protected static string GetString(string filename, int contentLength)
    {
        string retString;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            int length = (fs.Length < contentLength ? (int)fs.Length : contentLength);
            byte[] b = new byte[length];
            fs.Read(b, 0, contentLength);
            string str = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
            if (str.LastIndexOf("\r") > 0)
                retString = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf("\r"));
            else
                retString = str;
        }
        return retString;
    }
```

Then call it like this to write to new file:

```
string filename = "c:\\test.txt";
File.WriteAllText(filename,GetString(filename, 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void TrimTextFile(string fileName, long sizeInByte)
    {
        using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            fs.Position = sizeInByte;
            int byteRead = 0;
            while ((byteRead = fs.ReadByte()) >= 0)
            {
                if(byteRead == 13)
                {
                    fs.SetLength(fs.Position - 1);
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample code will continue reading lines writing them away again to another file up to a maximum file size specified. It converts each read line to your desired character encoding to determine its length in bytes.

Code is written without compile check.

```
var input = new FileStream(inputFilename, FileMode.Open);
var output = new FileStream(outputFilename, FileMode.Create);
var reader = new StreamReader(input);
var writer = new BinaryWriter(output);
var data = reader.ReadLine();
var maxSize = 10000;
var totalLength = 0;
while (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(data) && totalLength < maxSize)
{
  var bytes = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes(data);
  totalLength += bytes.GetLength(0);
  if totalLength < maxSize) writer.Write(bytes);
  data = reader.ReadLine();
}
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Just a tip to improve your code: Have you heard of `IDisposable` and `using`?

Comment: Yes, of course. But it detracts from the idea. I don't want to add too much noise to the answer.